# .Net Application accessing Outlook in Multi-user Environment

Tags: .net, citrix

I have a .net application that runs in a Citrix environment, this application is sending emails via outlook, only creating a new instance if not already running
However occasionally it picks up another users outlook and tries to send.

How can I get the current users process for Outlook ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please Check out [ask]... You'll have to elaborate a little more, is the email coming from a different `FromSender` or another user? Is it the account that is running the .Net application that is used to send emails? Are you certain another user didn't open the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WMI query to to get a list of processes by name. The `Win32_Process` object returned then contains a `GetOwner` method.

This example stores that information in a small class called `OwnedProcess`, and then returns an actual `Process` object for you to use. Note that it does return the `First()` match; assuming you don't care which instance of Outlook you pick up, as long as it is running under the correct user.

```
public class OwnedProcess
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public static Process GetProcessByOwner(string ProcessName, string Username)
    {
        OwnedProcess result;

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\cimv2");
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" + ProcessName + "'");

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

            IEnumerable<OwnedProcess> processes = BuildProcesses(collection);

            result = processes.Where(p => p.Owner.Equals(Username)).First();
        }

        Process processResult = Process.GetProcessById(result.Id);

        return processResult;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<OwnedProcess> BuildProcesses(ManagementObjectCollection WmiResults)
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject result in WmiResults)
        {
            string[] ownerName = new string[2];
            result.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", ownerName);

            yield return
                new OwnedProcess
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(result["ProcessId"]),
                    Name = result["Name"].ToString(),
                    Owner = ownerName[0]
                };
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be called as so:

```
string runningAs = Environment.UserName;
Process p = OwnedProcess.GetProcessByOwner("outlook.exe", runningAs);
```